# ordenar elementos dentro de un mapa (javascript)

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-3

estoy intentando poner dos geocoder dentro de un mapa. Un geocoder para origen y otro para destino. El problema es que no se como manejar el Estilo dentro del map para que un geocoder quede debajo de otro.
Comparto mi codigo javascript y el link del mapa.  http://190.220.132.134/usuariocontrol/urbano.php?a=162

```
 var map = new ol.Map({  
     view: new ol.View(),   
     layers: [
       new ol.layer.Tile({
         source: new ol.source.OSM({
       // wrapX: true
         })
       })
       ],

        target: document.getElementById('map'),

     controls: ol.control.defaults({
         zoom: false,     
       attributionOptions: {
         collapsible: false

       }
     }),

     view: new ol.View({
         center: ol.proj.transform(
                   [longitud, latitud], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
                // [0, 0], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
                   zoom: 11,
                   minZoom: 3,
                   maxZoom: 18

         })


   });


var geocoder = new Geocoder('nominatim', {
  provider: 'OSM',
 // key: 'Y1mwqAJLra9VSGEq3vx94nF8mrV6K9z2',
  lang: 'es-AR', //en-US, fr-FR
  //autoComplete: true,
  placeholder: 'Indique Origen ...',
  targetType: 'text-input',
  limit: 5,
  countrycodes:'AR',

  keepOpen: false
});
map.addControl(geocoder);



var geocoderdos = new Geocoder('nominatim', {
      provider: 'OSM',
     // key: 'Y1mwqAJLra9VSGEq3vx94nF8mrV6K9z2',
      lang: 'es-AR', //en-US, fr-FR
      //autoComplete: true,
      placeholder: 'Indique Destino ...',
      targetType: 'text-input',
      limit: 5,
      countrycodes:'AR',

      keepOpen: false
    });
    map.addControl(geocoderdos);
```

Comment: Hola, puedes usar la propiedad `position` al momento de añadir el control al mapa usando el método `map.controls.push()`. Podrías hacer algo así para el primer control: `map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(geocoder);`. Luego para `geocoder2` hace lo mismo pero cambias la posición: `map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(geocoder2);`. Prueba y comentas. Saludos

Comment: Hola Mauricio, esta perfecto pasa que yo uso openlayers, aunque ahora logre poner uno arriba de otro el problema es que cuando me tira la lista de posibilidades en search este me queda debajo del otro search dejandome la mitad de las opciones sin poder seleccionar

Comment: Entiendo, la verdad no he trabajado con `open-layers` asi que no creo poder ayudarte. Igual alguien te responderá. Agrega la etiqueta `open-layers` a ver si consigues llamar la atención. Saludos

Comment: Dale, muchisimas gracias amigo.

Comment: No pasa nada, y disculpa que me equivoqué. Leí en tu código `map` e inmediatamente mi mente se fue a Google Maps. Es qu estoy trabajando en un proyecto con Google Maps precisamente. 